# @vueform/multiselect Vue.js 3 - Clear input after select

Tags: vue.js, multi-select

I'm using multiselect v2.1.6 with vue.js 3.

```js
<multiselect
   v-model="value"
   :options="getSkillList"
   :searchable="true"
   @select="addSkill"
   @search-change="updates"
   ></multiselect>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to clear the input after I've selected something. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer:

```
     <multiselect
        v-model="value"
        :options="getSkillList"
        :searchable="true"
        @select="addSkill"
        @search-change="updates"
        ref="multiselect"
      ></multiselect>
```

Add ref="multiselect"

and then anywhere you want to reset the input you can add:

```
this.$refs.multiselect.clear();
```

Comment: Here's what works for me this.$refs.multiselect.deactivate(); More details from docs: https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-programmatic-control